# How can I write this regex without using a look behind that isn't supported

Tags: javascript, regex

I rarely use Regex's and I've gotten it to work on regex101.com

But I tried to use it and it says it's not supported by JS this is what I have

`/(?<=[\]|>])(.*?)(?=$|\n)/g`

https://regex101.com/r/sxUoDr/1

How can I substitute the look behind so it will work fine?

This is the data I'm trying to parse:

```
<100>11m
[RIP]25s
[RIP] 2m
[RIP] 7m
[RIP] 1m
[RIP]12s
```

I'm trying to extract the times away

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/sxUoDr/2

Comment: Maybe a simple `[^>|\]\n]+(?=\n|$)` is enough, but that's heavily dependant on your data, it will only work, if your border chars can't be contained in the data you want to extract

Comment: @AshishRanjan https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/230676/352329  Please post your pattern as an answer, this is how SO is designed to work.  Comments are to seek clarification/improvement. Please do your part to keep SO tidy and delete your comment.

Answer (score 0):

In javascript there is no look behind but if you want to 'extract' all the data you can use `RegExp#exec`:

```js
const data = `<100>11m
[RIP]25s
[RIP] 2m
[RIP] 7m
[RIP] 1m
[RIP]12s`

const getData = data => {
  const regex = /[ >\]]\s*(.*)/g
  const found = []
  let temp
  while(temp = regex.exec(data)){
    if (temp[1]) found.push(temp[1])
  }
  return found
}

console.log(getData(data))
```

And if you want to replace it you just have to add that extra selected char back:

```js
const data = `<100>11m
[RIP]25s
[RIP] 2m
[RIP] 7m
[RIP] 1m
[RIP]12s`.replace(/([ >\]])\s*(.*)/g, '$1 found [$2]')

console.log(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Without using a *look behind* lets use `.*\W(\w+)(?:\n|$)` to get your results. Regex Demo: https://regex101.com/r/zbvmfp/1

**JavaScript Demo**

```js
var pattern = /.*\W(\w+)(?:\n|$)/g;

var str = `<100>11m
[RIP]25s
[RIP] 2m
[RIP] 7m
[RIP] 1m
[RIP]12s`;

var result;

while (result = pattern.exec(str)) {
  console.log(result[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it can be written more simply than this...

```js
var rgx = /\d+[ms]/g;  // capture 1 or more digits followed by m or s
var str = `<100>11m
[RIP]25s
[RIP] 2m
[RIP] 7m
[RIP] 1m
[RIP]12s`;
var res;

while(res=rgx.exec(str)){
    console.log(res[0]);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Javascript does not support lookup behind. You can use positive lookups.

Regex: `/(?=\d+(m|s)).*$/gm`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RGM88x/2)